# Chained doOnNext works on method returning Flux, but not when called directly on a Flux object

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, netty, project-reactor

Using Spring Boot WebFlux, I noticed that `doOnNext` is executed on a Flux object
only before that object is assigned to a local variable.

In order to observe this behaviour I use an app
which is created with Spring initializr using default settings.
The only dependency I choose to add into POM is "Spring Reactive Web".

```java
@Controller
public class ProblemController {
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> upload(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Flux<DataBuffer> body = exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                // This prints!
                .doOnNext(db -> System.out.println("Bytes A: " + db.readableByteCount()));

        // Does not print anything...
        body.doOnNext(db -> System.out.println("Bytes B: " + db.readableByteCount()));

        return body
                .next()
                .map(db -> String.format("Uploaded %d bytes", db.readableByteCount()))
                .map(s -> new ResponseEntity<String>(s, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED));
    }
}
```

When I upload a file with

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload' \
--form 'file=@"/path/to/file.txt"'
```

I can see that only `Bytes A` message gets printed.

Even I add more `doOnNext` callbacks they all seem to be executed,

```
        Flux<DataBuffer> body = exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                // This prints!
                .doOnNext(db -> System.out.println("Bytes A: " + db.readableByteCount()))
                .doOnNext(db -> System.out.println("Bytes X: " + db.readableByteCount()));
```

Prints both `Bytes A` and `Bytes X`.

It never prints `Bytes C` though. Which gives me an impression that something in Flux object changes when it gets assigned to a local variable (`Flux<DataBuffer> body`).

What is really happening in this example?
And why I cannot see `Bytes C` printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each operator in Flux or Mono APIs returns a new instance. When you are chaining calls, you ultimately build upon each intermediate instance and get the "outer" one.

With your `Bytes C` example you've simply called the method without assigning the resulting new instance to any variable, so the instance has been garbage collected and was never made part of the execution path.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.chain

Comment: The answer is correct. The operators are not returning the object they applied on but a clone of that provider object. Data in a reactive stream does not flow until a consumer is connected (in this case we are in a WebFlux app, so it is consumed after returning from the controller method).

Comment: Although the easiest way to fix it so that `Bytes C` could be printed, is simply re-assign the returned object to `body` after adding the .doOnNext modifier, like: `body = body.doOnNext(db -> System.out.println("Bytes B: " + db.readableByteCount()));`